# Is there a way to replicate the setInterval function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I hope it's not very stupid, but,
I'm working in one building automation software by Siemens called Desigo, it supports javascript, but it's very limited. There is no setInterval built-in function which I really miss.
So is there a way to make something similar to setInterval using javascript? Or maybe using other languages..?
Hope it's not too silly.
Thanks

Comment: Probably not, as `setInterval` requires host-support: *any implementation would have to support some form of **asynchronous callbacks*** that could be 'triggered at a specific time'. XHR or even WebWorkers 'could' do this, but if there is no `setInterval`.. then other options are also probably limited.

Comment: I am not sure if my answer fulfills the standards of java script but i guess you can do this thing by calling an endless loop under the service worker if the environment allows.
Under this loop you can check the time and then call the function inside it after the interval provided by you.
But the question is if the environment doesn't supports simple methods of Javascript how would it support Service worker.